# Pygame UserPanel,Rotary,Boundaries

Tags: python, pygame

Firstly i need a userpanel. From there a user will enter 3 inputs. For example 1)What is your k? A)[USER İNPUT] 2) What is your M? B)[USER INPUT] 3)What is your a? C)[USER INPUT] whenever users apply these answers, pygame window will be open. The last answer will be our angle between the down platform of at the right side system and x direction. The other 2 answers will go arduino serial communation. Finally boundaries shoul be have. The circle can not pass up and down obstacles. Just pass from left side of the system. My code is below. Thanks four your answers,in advance :)

```
import pygame,sys
    pygame.init()


    win=pygame.display.set_mode((1030,650))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Seri Manipulator Kontrolü")

    x = 700
    y = 300
    width = 5
    height = 0
    vel = 5
    oxu= 870
    oyu= 420
    owu= 160
    ohu= 10
    oxd= 870
    oyd= 220
    owd= 160
    ohd= 10
    centeredobx=870
    centeredoby=230
    centeredboy=190
    centereden=10
    cubukx= 880
    cubuky= 320
    cubuken= 140
    cubukboy= 10


    def yazdir():
                    win.fill((0,0,0))
                    pygame.draw.circle(win, (0, 127, 255), (x, y), width, 0)
                    pygame.draw.rect(win, (255, 0, 0), (oxu, oyu, owu, ohu))
                    pygame.draw.rect(win, (255, 0, 0), (oxd, oyd, owd, ohd))
                    pygame.draw.rect(win, (255, 255, 0), (centeredobx, centeredoby, centereden, centeredboy))
                    pygame.draw.rect(win, (128, 128, 128), (cubukx, cubuky, cubuken, cubukboy))
                    pygame.draw.rect(win, (255, 0, 0), (1020, 220, 10, 200))
                    pygame.display.update()



    run = True
    while run:
        pygame.time.delay(100)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            print(event)
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
                pygame.quit()


        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if pygame.key.get_pressed() and x in range(865,1025) and y in range(225,235) or pygame.key.get_pressed() and x in range(865,1025) and y in range(415,425):
        return

    else:
            if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and 1010 > x > 860 and 235 <= y <= 415 and centeredobx <= 1005:
                centeredobx += vel
                cubukx += vel
                cubuken -= vel
                yazdir()

            if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and 1010 > x > 860 and 235 <= y <= 415 and centeredobx >= 875:
                centeredobx -= vel
                cubukx -= vel
                cubuken += vel
                yazdir()


            if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and x > 5:
                x -= vel
                yazdir()

            if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and x < 1005: 
                x += vel
                yazdir()

            if keys[pygame.K_UP] and y > 5 :
                y -= vel
                yazdir()

            if keys[pygame.K_DOWN] and y < 645:
                y += vel
                yazdir()




    pygame.quit()
```